# Python Multiprocessing bug

Tags: python, debugging, multiprocessing

```
import time
import multiprocessing

def do_something():
   
    print('Sleeping 1 second...')
    time.sleep(1)
    print('Done Sleeping')

if __name__ =='__main__':
    start = time.perf_counter()

    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_something())
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_something())

    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()

    finish = time.perf_counter()

    print(f'Finished in {round(finish-start, 2)} second(s)')
```

I have been trying to do multiprocessing, yet I keep getting 2.45 seconds from the above code.

I got this code from a youtube video, but the person got 1.01 seconds while I got 2.45 seconds. Does this happen to you guys? If not, could any of you tell me why? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You have to put the function as the target and not run the function.

The issue is in this line:

When you put the target as the function with brackets it runs the function in the main thread. Which in turn stops the whole program, rather only give the function.

```
p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_something)
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_something)
```

Full code:

```
import time
import multiprocessing

def do_something():
   
    print('Sleeping 1 second...')
    time.sleep(1)
    print('Done Sleeping')

if __name__ =='__main__':
    start = time.perf_counter()

    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_something)
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_something)

    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()

    finish = time.perf_counter()

    print(f'Finished in {round(finish-start, 2)} second(s)')
```

And then on my machine it gives me 1.23 secs. It will vary on different machines.

Comment: thankssss that solves my problem